# MySQL not starting on MAMP. Nothing is working

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've installed `MAMP` on clean `Windows 10` installation. When I try to run MAMP, it starts Apache server and doesn't start `MySQL server`. I've searched and tried many different options but none of these help.

What I've tried:

1. Uninstall / Install MAMP again
2. Delete ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1
3. Try different ports (3306, 8888)
4. Type killall -9 msqld

Here is what error log says:

> 2019-02-20T10:13:34.538252Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>
> 2019-02-20T10:13:34.538322Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled.
>
> 2019-02-20T10:13:34.538601Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 10184

Comment: What happens if you type C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe into a command window?

Comment: mysqld: Can't change dir to 'C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)2019-02-20T10:48:36.556105Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\data\ALEX-ACER.lower-test
2019-02-20T10:48:36.556288Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\data\ALEX-ACER.lower-test
2019-02-20T10:48:36.557266Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\data\
2019-02-20T10:48:36.575904Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: I've created data folder manually and now nothing happens when I type C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe in terminal

Comment: This feels like a permissions problem. I haven't used MAMP in years (or Windows for that matter), but make sure the MySQL Daemon has read/write permissions

Comment: Any suggestion where can I find this setting? I'm already running MAMP as administrator

Comment: Did you install MAMP as administrator? I'm guessing the services (MySQL and Apache) will not run as administrator. You could grant read-write permissions to the directories using explorer and see if that changes anything...

Comment: Yes, I've installed everything as admin, but that was not the issue. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing older version of MAMP (3.3.1), which is working fine now. Seems that version 4.1.0 is not stable or not compatible with my Windows.